# Filter insensitive case

Tags: javascript, php

## this code is in case sensitive, will you give some code not to case sensitive

====================================================================

```
var $rows = $('tbody > tr'),
    $filters = $('#filter_table input');

$filters.on("keyup", function () {
    var $i = $filters.filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
    }),
        len = $i.length;

    if (len === 0) return $rows.show();

    var cls = '.' + $i.map(function () {
        return this.className
    }).get().join(',.');

    $rows.hide().filter(function () {
        return $('td', this).filter(cls).filter(function () {
            var content = this.textContent,
                inputVal = $i.filter('.' + this.className).val();

            return content.indexOf(inputVal) > -1;

        }).length === len;
    }).show();
});
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet the question is to make the code not to be case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rows.hide().filter(function () {
    return $('td', this).filter(cls).filter(function () {
        var content = this.textContent,
            inputVal = $i.filter('.' + this.className).val();

        return content.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal.toLowerCase()) > -1;

    }).length === len;
}).show();
```

The idea is to convert both value to lowercase and compare them

Comment: thank you very big help!

Comment: @Darsil: Do mark it as answer for other developer as reference in case others find similar problem, thanks